# Can someone marry to the Step Mother's sister?

Tags: sharia, nikah

The guy was not breast feeder when his father got a new mother for him. Can he get married to the sister of the new mother? the boy was matured when his father got married to this lady)

Answer (score 2):

Yes a man can marry the sister of his step mother, but could never marry his step mother as she is a mahram because of ([4:22](http://legacy.quran.com/4/22)) which make all wife's of the father haram to his sons,

> And **do not marry those** [**women**] **whom your fathers married**, except what has already occurred. ...

the other mahrams could be find in ([4:23](http://legacy.quran.com/4/23)) so except for those any other women are halal to marry (assuming that slavery is void) as quoted in ([4:24](http://legacy.quran.com/4/24)):

> And [also prohibited to you are all] married women except those your right hands possess. [This is] the decree of Allah upon you. And lawful to you are [**all others**] **beyond these**, [provided] that you seek them [in marriage] with [gifts from] your property, desiring chastity, not unlawful sexual intercourse. ...

-of course with details which could be find in ahadith (for example aunts of the wife, who are made haram for the husband unless he is legally separated from his wife)-.

---

As sisters of a step mother are **non-mahram** scholars say that the step son shouldn't meet them without a mahram and they shouldn't appear unveiled in front of him unless he was breast-fed by his step-mother!

---

But generally a mahram is either by [alliance](http://islamqa.info/en/20750) (marriage: mother, step-mother, grand-fathers-wife, wife's-mother or grandmother, daughter of a wife, son's or grandson's wife), lineage (ancestors like father mother grandfather grandmother, descent daughters, sons, grandchildren) and by breast-feeding.

Here are two Fatwas in Arabic as a reference [1](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/174057) & [2](http://islamqa.info/ar/153700)

And Allah knows best!

Comment: It would be more helpful and useful if you could please post those referenced Ayats/Hadiths so we don't have to go link hunting. I am currently behind a proxy so I am unable to visit or view those sites.

Comment: I think then there should be a 'spoiler' kinda tag that can be used to collapse a whole section that has references to Hadith that will always be collapsed when user visits the page, so then the answer won't scare of the user upon first glance. That way you can keep all your explanation in open while the exact quote in spoiler tag (collapsed). I think we should make this suggestion in the meta so to bring it to Mods' attention about our requested feature.

Comment: What about the Feature Request? Is it good enough to be requested or...?

Comment: I was wondering if you could do it instead. I would be grateful. Thank you. :)

Comment: Yes, of course. Please go ahead. I won't sue you. :P But I am worried our discussion like this in the comments may attract eye of an Mod. So please go ahead and post the request on whichever site seems more appropriate to you.

Answer (score -4):

Marriage to the following is prohibited:

Uterine females.

Foster sisters.

Step Mothers and step daughters.

Other than this, all are allowed.